# Data transfer between two remote servers linux (sftp)

Tags: command-line, ssh, scripts, sftp

I work remotely trough my Linux system. I have data on server A which can be accessed only through SFTP. The second server is an HPC cluster. 
I want to fetch data in my HPC cluster working directory from server A.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access to Server A, you should install an sshd daemon on it and then open the correct ports on the firewall of server A and then mount the appropriate share on the HPC cluster using `sshfs`.

If you have no root access to server A, then the security design of your environment is what you have and there is nothing you can do...

Comment: Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news ;)